# Python's numpy array of doubles to and from a HDF file without unnecessary conversions

Tags: python, numpy, h5py, hdf

I have a numpy array of doubles. np.array([double1, double2, double3, ... , doublen])
All array's elements are successive in memory.
I want to use a HDF file as a data container (save / load).

save is implemented as:
hdf.create_dataset(name='data', data=np.array([double1, double2, double3, ... , doublen]))

load is implemented as:
data = np.array(hdf_group['data'])

How can I verify that no unnecessary conversions like double to string to double occurs?

Comment: Look at `hdf_group['data'].dtype`

Answer (score 0):

The variable dtype remains unchanged throughout the process. You can verify by checking dtype as you go. Code below demonstrates behavior. (I created variable `arr` to hold the array of np.doubles before loading to HDF5.)

```
double1 = np.double(1) 
double2 = np.double(2)
double3 = np.double(3)
doublen = np.double(10)

with h5py.File('SO_70168153.h5','w') as hdf:
    arr = np.array([double1, double2, double3, doublen])
    print(f"np.array:\nShape: {arr.shape}, Dtype: {arr.dtype}")
    print(arr[:])

    hdf.create_dataset(name='data', data=arr )
    print(f"HDF dataset:\nShape: {hdf['data'].shape}, Dtype: {hdf['data'].dtype}")
    print(hdf['data'][:])

    data = hdf['data'][:]
    print(f"data array:\nShape: {data.shape}, Dtype: {data.dtype}")
    print(data[:])
```

Output from above:

```
np.array:
Shape: (4,), Dtype: float64
[ 1.  2.  3. 10.]
HDF dataset:
Shape: (4,), Dtype: float64
[ 1.  2.  3. 10.]
data array:
Shape: (4,), Dtype: float64
[ 1.  2.  3. 10.]
```